# Raise an event in download class and catch it in the current page in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

In my Windows Phone application, I am downloading some files from server using a file download  class. I want to raise an event with the details of finished file and catch that event in current page. How can I handle this process in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using delegate events by sending the downloaded file as the event parameter.